# How can I stabilize the performance of a CNN on the test set?

Tags: deep-learning

I am handling a binary classification dataset of images. Both the loss and accuracy on the test set oscillates much - the results are not stable. The network already reaches 100% accuracy on the training set and cross entropy at about 1e-4, whereas on the test set the accuracy varies between 0.6 to 1 and cross entropy between 0.3 to 1.1.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the dataset is rather small, with 64 cases. Augmentation is performed and the results above are from a 4-fold cross valiation

Comment: Flagged as a question that should be asked at stats.stackexchange.com